# How to serialize a VARIANT or BSTR?

Tags: c++, com, marshalling

I am trying to figure out some COM marshalling features.  Eventually, I want to persist a deeply nested variant array to file but I am trying first with a simple string.  I realise these APIs are meant for remote procedure calls but I was hoping this serialization was also suitable for file persistence.

I work a lot with Excel VBA and to discover this serialization APIs is a real eye opener.

The code below serializes a BSTR to a buffer, the buffer is copied which will serve as a substitute for saving to and loading from a file.

The current problem is the BSTR_UserUnmarshal is throwing an exception `Unhandled exception at 0x7631C762 (KernelBase.dll) in RPCMarshalling.exe: 0x00000057: The parameter is incorrect. occurred`

I probably have the syntax wrong because I am working with scraps of sample code.  The goal is to get the string from srctest to desttest with RPC serialization API calls.

```
// RPCMarshalling.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

//https://searchcode.com/file/140723732/dlls/oleaut32/tmarshal.c#l-818

typedef struct _marshal_state {
    LPBYTE  base;
    int     size;
    int     curoff;
} marshal_state;


int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(0);

    CComBSTR srctest("Hello");
    marshal_state srcbuf;
    memset(&srcbuf, 0, sizeof(srcbuf));
    ULONG flags = MAKELONG(MSHCTX_DIFFERENTMACHINE, NDR_LOCAL_DATA_REPRESENTATION);

    ULONG size = ::BSTR_UserSize(&flags, 0, &srctest);

    DWORD newsize = max(size, 256);
    (&srcbuf)->base = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, newsize);
    if (!(&srcbuf)->base)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    ::BSTR_UserMarshal(&flags, (&srcbuf)->base + (&srcbuf)->curoff, &srctest);
    (&srcbuf)->curoff = size;


    std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << size << "\n";


    marshal_state destbuf;
    memset(&destbuf, 0, sizeof(destbuf));

    (&destbuf)->base = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, newsize);
    if (!(&destbuf)->base)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    /* pretend we are loading from file saved by src buffer */
    RtlCopyMemory((&destbuf)->base, (&srcbuf)->base, newsize);


    CComBSTR desttest("");
    BSTR deststring;

    try
    {
        unsigned char *buffer;
        buffer = ::BSTR_UserUnmarshal(&flags, (&destbuf)->base, &deststring);
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error:" << e << "\n" << size << "\n";
    }



    ::CoUninitialize();

}
```

Comment: Although I think it used to work (long time ago), it doesn't any more because the first argument to [type]_UserUnmarshal is in fact a pointer to a USER_MARSHAL_CB structure (and first member is indeed the flags). Yes, this is not documented like that, but it's true (try with VARIANT instead of BSTR, and it will just crash). This structure is filled by the RPC code (and also by what MIDL builds when you build an RPC interface). Makes it almost impossible to use out of RPC context. If you want to have a look at what it likes, just build a simple idl that contains a BSTR in a method.

Comment: PS: for serializing a BSTR, you don't need that, just write the length and the bytes  :-)

Comment: @Simon: Next step is serializing nested Variant arrays.  This is just the first step.

Comment: You could try StgSerializePropVariant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-stgserializepropvariant (cast your VARIANT* into a PROPVARIANT*). I know it works for relatively complex stuff.

Comment: @SimonMourier : I have created an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to achieve the goal of serializing a Variant (as per OP's question text)   Work in progress, using Simon Mourier's suggestion about StgSerializePropVariant

```
int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(0);

    CComVariant srctest("Hello");

    SERIALIZEDPROPERTYVALUE* serialized;
    ULONG cb;
    ::StgSerializePropVariant((PROPVARIANT*)&srctest, &serialized, &cb);

    CComVariant pvDest;
    ::StgDeserializePropVariant(serialized, cb, (PROPVARIANT*)&pvDest);

    CoTaskMemFree(serialized);

    CComBSTR strDest(pvDest.bstrVal);
    std::cout << "This got serialized:\n" << LPCSTR(_bstr_t(strDest, true)) << "\n";

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Big memory leaks: you need to free PROPVARIANTs, and the allocated serialized buffer as well. That's what I said it was easier to cast to PROPVARIANT* and continue to use ATL's smart wrapper classes. Basically a PROPVARIANT is a VARIANT (reverse is false), so since you're using only VARIANT types all the way, you should'nt have any specific issue. This is a code that works and doesn't leak: https://pastebin.com/raw/Udhr3RM6  otherwise use PropVariantClear when needed.

Comment: @SimonMourier : ok, I have adopted your code in this answer.  But also, whilst poking around the method of CComVariant I found WriteToStream/ReadFromStream and so I have added another answer.  Perhaps you can code review it as well please.  Cheers.

Comment: Memory leaks are now gone. Not sure why you use _bstr_t. Either you use CComXXX classes that come with ATL, or use _bstr_t and _variant_t that come with Visual Studio C++ compile. Both are ok but you shouldn't mix them IMHO. In fact ATL has more feature, like the Read/Write Stream methods. And for that matter, the source is available so you can have a look at what they do. I bet they support less combination than proputil.dll. Plus they don't support PROPVARIANTs types, should you ever need it someday.

Comment: that _bstr_t is just because I couldn't figure out a way to write a CComBSTR to std:cout.

Comment: Just push CComBSTR to cout, it will be converted to what's needed. If you really want the underlying pointer, you can use the `m_str` member.

Comment: that doesn't work for me that prints the address (both when CComBSTR instance itself and when `m_str `)

Answer (score 0):

And actually if serializing is the goal then why not serialize to an IStream

```
int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(0);

    CComVariant srctest("Hello");

    CComPtr<IStream> pStream;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE,(LPSTREAM *) &pStream.p);
    if (hr != S_OK) return hr;

    hr = srctest.WriteToStream(pStream, VT_BSTR);
    if (hr != S_OK) return hr;

    {
        // stream needs resetting to the start before we 
        // attempt to read it
        LARGE_INTEGER  dlibMove;
        dlibMove.HighPart = 0;
        dlibMove.LowPart = 0;
        DWORD dwOrigin;
        dwOrigin = 0;
        ULARGE_INTEGER  libNewPosition;
        hr = pStream->Seek(dlibMove, dwOrigin, &libNewPosition);
        if (hr != S_OK) return hr;
    }

    CComVariant pvDest;
    hr = pvDest.ReadFromStream(pStream, VT_BSTR);
    if (hr != S_OK) return hr;

    CComBSTR strDest(pvDest.bstrVal);
    std::cout << "This got serialized:\n" << LPCSTR(_bstr_t(strDest, true)) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "This got serialized:\n" << strDest.m_str << "\n";

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak again :-) You must release the stream (you asked CreateStreamOnHGlobal to free memory when the stream is released), or just declare it as CComPtr<IStream> instead so it will be released smartly.

Answer (score 0):

StgSerializePropVariant solution have memory boundary problem with VT_BSTR, if the wchar_t is not allocated sequentially with Variant;

The CComVariant::WriteToStream solution not working with VT_ARRAY.

Please refer to [Convert VARIANT to bytes and vise versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464971/convert-variant-to-bytes-and-vise-versa), It offers a better solution for me.